# SoapUI isn't getting response from Web Service - ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, soapui

I am trying to send a soap request of a Web Service to SoapUI tool and getting the following error:

```
12/10/17 09:00:33 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl
12/10/17 09:00:33   at br.gov.suframa.pmn.webservices.handler.SegurancaHandler.validarEntrada(SegurancaHandler.java:161)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at br.gov.suframa.pmn.webservices.handler.SegurancaHandler.handleMessage(SegurancaHandler.java:74)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at br.gov.suframa.pmn.webservices.handler.SegurancaHandler.handleMessage(SegurancaHandler.java:33)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandleMessage(HandlerProcessor.java:292)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandlersRequest(HandlerProcessor.java:135)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ServerSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnRequest(ServerSOAPHandlerTube.java:134)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube.processRequest(HandlerTube.java:116)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:471)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:136)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:857)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:313)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:199)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
12/10/17 09:00:33   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I have read couple of posts around this problem, but nobody has clearly provided the solution. I try to follow the tip of this post: [Exception occurs with JAX-RPC handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545496/exception-occurs-with-jax-rpc-handler)
but I have just one lib "saaj-api-1.3.jar" that´s contains "SOAPElement.class" and no other lib with this class.

Do I need to add any jars? Can some one help me resolving this?

I am running this program as a Java app from eclipse and on JRE 1.5.0_24.

****UPDATE**
I noticed in soapUI, I try to send one well formated xml with parameter and when I was debugging, I discovered that in the SOAP request is sent one "\n" instead of a content. I want to pass a xml parameter.

Did someone had the same situation?**

Answer (score 0):

Remove all spaces from xml request from soapui and it will work.